# how to invite facebook friends to my website through email

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, yii2

I know this question is already there. But my requirement is different. I have a social website where I want to invite facebook friends. The invitation should go to there email ids in place of message or notification. I have already tried

1. FB.ui({ method: 'send',name: 'Some Name',link: 'https://website.com/', description: 'Some description', picture: 'image.jpg'});
   }

this is sending one message to selected friends. Also

2. FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',message: 'Invite your Facebook Friends' });

this is sending one notification.

Both are working but as I said I need email should trigger after selecting friend.

please let me know if you have any solution regarding this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: present an email field where the user can enter the email of a friend, and send him an email.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @luschn but what if I have 1000 facebook friends. Then I need to give 1000 emails manually which is not best approach I think.

Comment: you don´t want to invite 1000 friends to an app, right? that would be spam.

Comment: Its not an App its a Website

Comment: an app can be attached to a website, and you are talking about FB.ui methods in your question - you can only use those with an app. either way, check out my answer.

Comment: ok. the point is its not possible to send email invitation right? Thanks for your time buddy.

Comment: exactly. as you can read in my answer, there is no way to get access to emails of friends without their explicit authorization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to invite users by email. The only way to get the email of a user is to authorize that user with the email permission. You can´t get the emails of friends in any way.

You will have to create your own invite method by presenting an email field and sending an email to a friend with your platform of choice (php mail, for example).